# Who were the בני ברית מערביים mentioned in the Trumas HaDeshen, and what was their agenda?

Tags: history

The Trumas HaDeshen #88 in chelek 2, seen [here](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=1835&st=&pgnum=171&hilite=) discussed going to live in Eretz Yisroel in his times.

In his discussion he mentions

> בני ברית מערביים נחשבים לרשעים גמורים מוסרים מפורסמים
>   והם טורדים ומבלבלים האשכנזים שהם שומרי  תורה

Who are these בני ברית מערביים and what were they doing?
I'm assuming he means middle eastern Jews so I wonder if they were still practicing Judaism or perhaps they had converted to Islam. He does call them Bnei Bris, but at the same time he implies that the Ashkenzi (immigrants?) were the ones keeping the Torah. Why were these other people so intent on ruining it for the Ashkenazim?

Later on he mentions רשעת הישמעלים so these people were not Muslim, not that it's likely he would call a Muslim Bnei Bris.

A quick reference point, the [author of Trumas HaDeshen Rabbi Yisroel Isserlein](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Isserlein) died 26 years before the [Ottoman conquest of the Holy land](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/History_of_Palestine#Ottoman_era), so whatever political issues were going on were still under the rule of the Mamluks

Comment: It is quite possible that he is referring to non-Muslim Arabs descended from Yishmael who are living in the land of Israel. They are also called 'Bnai Yishmael' and do have a tradition of keeping the covenant which they received from Avraham.  It is not the Torah but something akin to the seven laws of Noach. That is to distinguish them from the balance of Muslims in the area.

Comment: Maybe he’s referring to (assimilated?) Jews who live in Arab countries? Can you share some more context?

Comment: @DonielF Could be. I used converted to Islam as a similar suggestion. Seems to be a more period accurate guess. But I don't know. I have no other information to offer.

Comment: @DonielF The language of the Trumat HaDeshen would be different if he was referring to assimilated Jews. The Hebrew is "בני ברית מערביים"which means that they are actual Arabs who are included in a covenant. A Jew who converts to Islam does not become an Arab. They become a Muslim. They would be called a "משומד". It is possible that he could be referring to Jewish converts who were of Arab background who are known informants. But that seems highly unlikely.

Comment: @DonielF And if you read the whole response, it seems to clarify that those Arabs who are 'Bnai Brit' are actually called "Yishmaelim" in the closing words. In other words, they are cousins to Jews. In Midrashim, like Sefer HaYashar, they distinguish between descendants from Yishmael and other inhabitants of the Arab middle east.

Comment: @YaacovDeane And for reasons like that a little context would be nice, as per my previous comment. :)

Comment: @DonielF Context of what? That descendents of Ishmael have a covenant they continue from Avraham (Ibrahim)? Thinking a little further, Arab could also be referring to Nabateans like is mentioned by Josephus in The Jewish War. 1:87.

Comment: For more detail, see the paragraph beginning, "In Hebrew" dealing with the origin of the term 'Arab'.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_(etymology)

Comment: @YaacovDeane Context of the tiny little snippet in the OP. What’s the Teshuvah talking about?

Comment: @Shimon bM Sorry. Forgot to ping you. This was my question that needs some historical clarification. Looks like something you can help with?

Comment: @DonielF Sorry. The question isn't mine. But the response from the Trumat HaDeshen is dealing with whether it was considered a mitzvah in his day to make aliyah to the land of Israel in general and Jerusalem specifically. His response was that there are enormous benefits but that doing so in his day was very difficult (lack of food, etc) and dangerous (because the Arab population was very hostile to Jews). In addition to this, he said because the Yishmaelim were "Bnai Brit", it was confusing for Ashkenazi Jews.

Comment: Remember that this was being written around 1440 or 1450. That's like 570 years ago.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[According](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=94&book=15011) to [Rabbi Yehudah Leib Maimon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yehuda_Leib_Maimon) in Sefer Zikaron Leshlomo Meir Sali, this is a reference to some Sephardic Jews living in Eretz Yisrael who would inform on the Jews who came to live in Yisrael, especially the Ashkenazim. These "mosrim" were considered at times among the "z'kenim" of Yerushalayim; meaning they were considered to being men of stature, though clearly, they weren't really. It seems they gained this status by inducing fear. Thus, by the time of Rabbi Ovadyah of Bartenura, a number of decades after Rabbi Isserlein, Yerushalayim's Jewish community had become considerably smaller. According to Rabbi Maimon, based on what the Bartenura wrote, it seems they did this purely for monetary reasons.

[Rabbi Yisrael Hess](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israel_Hess) in Or Hamizrach, vol. 21, also [notes](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=11&book=16346) that this term refers to Sephardic Jews.

Dr. Avraham David in Al Bamotei Hatzvi, on the other hand, [thought](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=17&book=192248) this may be a reference to the "Edah Hamughrabit", i.e., Jews from North Africa, who got into an inter-edah fight with the Ashkenazim, and not necessarily "z'kenim"-leaders.  [Rabbi Eliyahu Zini](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eliyahu_Zini) in [Eretz Chemdatenu](https://tablet.otzar.org/pages/?&restore=1&t=1587320370333&pagenum=117&book=625875) also wrote that this refers to North-African Jews.

Comment: Thank you! (15)

Comment: @user6591 You're welcome!